# R: Simplex error: NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Tags: r, linear-programming

For the following minimization with objective function and constraints, `boot.simplex` returns an error:

```
Error in tab[-pr, ] <- tab[-pr, ] - (tab[-pr, pc]/pv) %o% tab[pr, ] : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

The code is here:

```
library(boot)
a = c(1, 1, 1)
A2 = rbind(c(2, 7.5, 3), c(20, 5, 10))
b2 = c(10000, 30000)
simplex(a=a, A2=A2, b2=b2, maxi=FALSE)
```

Note that the constraints are only of the greater-than-equal-to type.

But, if a bogus less-than-or-equal-to constraint is added as shown below, a valid result is returned.

```
A1 = c(1, 0, 0)
b1 = 1000000
simplex(a=a, A1=A1, b1=b1, A2=A2, b2=b2, maxi=FALSE)
```

The optimal solution to the second attempt is below

```
Optimal solution has the following values
  x1   x2   x3 
1250 1000    0 
The optimal value of the objective  function is 2250.
```

Why is there an error with the first attempt?  Is it not allowed to only use `>=` type of constraints?  What is a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437781/a-basic-example-of-the-simplex-function-in-r-with-errors `simplex(a=a, A1=c(1,1,1),b1 = 1.0E+12,A2=A2, b2=b2, maxi=FALSE)` works for me

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  Seems to be the same issue.  Wonder why a fake (A1, b1) pair is needed.  Is (A1, b1) always required?

Comment: I have not been able to find a example without the pair (A1, b1) Maybe it is a bug... Anyway, I'm happy the link helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the value of the default eps, and it works for me.
The default is `eps=1e-10`, try to increase it.

```
simplex(a=a, A2=A2, b2=b2, maxi=FALSE, eps=1e-6)
```